# how do i backup a database in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

i'm running my app using docker-compose with the below yml file

```
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=42EXP
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}

  node:
    container_name: node
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgresdata:
```

As you can see  here ,i'm using a `named volume` to manage postgres state.

According to the official docs, i can backup a volume like the below

```
docker run --rm --volumes postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata
```

Some other tutorials suggested i use the `pg-dump` function provided by postgres for backups.

```
pg_dump -Fc database_name_here > database.bak
```

I guess i would have to go inside the postgres container to perform this function and mount the backup directory to the host.

Is one approach better/preferable than the other?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To run pg_dump you can use `docker exec` command:

**To backup:**

`docker exec -u <your_postgres_user> <postgres_container_name> pg_dump -Fc <database_name_here> > db.dump`

**To drop db (Don't do it on production, for test purpose only!!!):**

`docker exec -u <your_postgres_user> <postgres_container_name> psql -c 'DROP DATABASE <your_db_name>'`

**To restore:**

`docker exec -i -u <your_postgres_user> <postgres_container_name> pg_restore -C -d postgres < db.dump`

Also you can use docker-compose analog of exec. In that case you can use short services name (postgres) instead of full container name (composeproject_postgres).

[docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)

[docker-compose exec](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/)

[pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html)

Comment: When I call 
docker exec -u <your_postgres_user> <postgres_container_name> pg_restore -C -d postgres < db.dump
the call is hanging.

Comment: My bad, you should add --interactive option for docker exec. I've edited original answer to fix this.

Comment: small typo : s/DATABSE/DATABASE/ (thanks for the answer ;-)

Comment: With postgres:9.4 docker image the following command works for me `docker exec <postgres_container_name> psql -U <your_postgres_user> -c 'DROP DATABASE <your_db_name>'` So command against the container is executed as root user, but Postgres'es user is defined in the PSQL command. Otherwise I get error that my Postgres user does not have password.

Comment: When running the DROP DATABASE command I am getting this error: ERROR: cannot drop the currently open database

Comment: The bad thing about this answer is that the exec will fail if the container is not running, while the run runs a container to execute the command on it.

If you run the command as is and the container is not running the db.dump file with the last dump it will be deleted and replaced with a db.dump file with an error message and you may lose your backup.

Comment: For docker compose...

Backup: `docker-compose exec -u <postgres_user_name> <postgres_container_name> pg_dump -Fc <database_name_here> > db.dump`

Restore: `docker-compose exec -T -u <postgres_user_name> <postgres_container_name> -C -d postgres < db.dump`

Answer (score 3):

Since you have

```
expose:     
 - "5432"
```

you can run

```
pg_dump -U <user> -h localhost -Fc <db_name> > 1.dump
```

pg_dump connects to 5432 port to make dump since it is listened by postgres in container you will dump db from container

Answer (score 1):

You can also run

```
docker-compose exec -T postgres sh -c 'pg_dump -cU $POSTGRES_USER $POSTGRES_DB' | gzip > netbox.sql.gz
```

where `netbox.sql.gz` is the name of the backup file.

restoring would be

```
gunzip -c netbox.sql.gz | docker-compose exec -T postgres sh -c 'psql -U $POSTGRES_USER $POSTGRES_DB'
```