# How to access a file from host machine on docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker, file

I want to access a file from host machine in docker. I found -v is a good option but it is working with `run` not with `exec`. I want to connect to a postgres database and need to access a dump file on my host machine. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access files in host from a Docker Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55104551/how-to-access-files-in-host-from-a-docker-container)

Comment: The answers is applicable while using `docker run` but not `docker exec` and I need to use  `docker exec`

Comment: You can run `pgrestore` or `psql` from the host system, targeting a published port from the database container, without using any `docker` commands at all.  You should not normally need `docker exec` to access a database.

Comment: [how do i backup a database in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210274/how-do-i-backup-a-database-in-docker) also discusses this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically add volume mappings to a running container. But you can copy files into the container using `docker cp`.

When you've copied the file into the container, you can then use it inside the container on your `docker exec` command.